# Groovy custom sort a map by value

Tags: sorting, groovy, dictionary

I have a map such as

```
m=[
     "james":"silly boy",
     "janny":"Crazy girl",
     "jimmy":"funny man",
     "georges":"massive fella"
];
```

I want to sort this map by its value but **ignoring the case** (this is really why the custom sort is needed). Hence I figured I had to implement a custom sort using a closure. But I'm brand new at Groovy and been struggling to get this very simple task done!

The desired results would be:

```
["janny":"Crazy girl", "jimmy":"funny man", "georges":"massive fella", "james":"silly boy"]
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To sort with case insensitive, use

```
m.sort { it.value.toLowerCase() }
```

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you mean you want to sort on value, you can just do:

```
Map m =[ james  :"silly boy",
         janny  :"Crazy girl",
         jimmy  :"funny man",
         georges:"massive fella" ]

Map sorted = m.sort { a, b -> a.value <=> b.value }
```

Comment: Also equivalent to `m.sort { it.value }`

Comment: This use natural ordering (or sorting) which is case sensitive. How can I make this case insensitive ?

Comment: m.sort { a, b -> a.value.toLowerCase() <=> b.value.toLowerCase() } is the correct answer for this other solution :)

Answer (score 8):

If somebody is looking for how to make it work in the Jenkins pipeline script, you will have to create a separate method with `@NonCPS` annotation for that:

```
@NonCPS
def getSorted(def mapSizeMap){
    mapSizeMap.sort(){ a, b -> b.value <=> a.value }
}
```

And then call it from the pipeline script.

`def sortedMapZoneMap = getSorted(mapZonesMap)`

You can of course apply "case sensitive" logic on top.

Comment: Confirmed, I've been fighting this in a Jenkins pipeline and your suggestion is working for me. Thank you.

Comment: Actually it would make sense to create a separete question for that, that would include Jenkins pipelein in the title. Then it will be easier to find. I also spend a lot of time looking for solution :)

Comment: I created a separate question for that :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121651/groovy-jenkins-pipeline-script-sort-a-map-by-value/63121652#63121652

I hope it will be easier to find. If somebody could upvode, I will be glad :)

Answer (score 5):

BTW, here is code which is showing different sorting with and without toLowerCase():

```
Map m =[ james  :"silly boy",
         janny  :"crazy girl",
         jimmy  :"Funny man",
         georges:"massive fella" ]
Map sorted = m.sort { a, b -> a.value <=> b.value }
println sorted
sorted = m.sort { a, b -> a.value.toLowerCase() <=> b.value.toLowerCase() }
println sorted
```

And wll print:

```
[jimmy:Funny man, janny:crazy girl, georges:massive fella, james:silly boy]
[janny:crazy girl, jimmy:Funny man, georges:massive fella, james:silly boy]
```