# Groovy Sorting a map by integer value (highest value first)

Tags: sorting, groovy

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686659/groovy-custom-sort-a-map-by-value) but the one key difference is the values to be sorted are integers. So for example I have

```
  def acctressesByHotnessLevel=[
        "Jennifer Lawrence":8,
        "Emma Watson":9,
        "Felicity Jones":8,
        "Brie Larson":10
 ];

Map sorted = acctressesByHotnessLevel.sort { a, b -> a.value <=> b.value }
sorted.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }
```

Right now this prints the value with the lowest integer first, but I want the highest value to be printed first.

Comment: Pretty lame example code... :-(

Comment: what's lame about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either swap your sort comparison:

```
Map sorted = acctressesByHotnessLevel.sort { a, b -> b.value <=> a.value }
```

Or use `reverseEach`:

```
sorted.reverseEach { k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }
```