# Sort map by value in Groovy jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How to do custom sort of `Map` for example by value in Jekins pipeline script?

This code doesn't quite work in Jenkins pipeline script:

```
Map m =[ james  :"silly boy",
         janny  :"Crazy girl",
         jimmy  :"funny man",
         georges:"massive fella" ]

Map sorted = m.sort { a, b -> a.value <=> b.value }
```

The map is still not sorted.

I decided to crate a separate question with better name and tags, because many people were struggling to find an answer here:
[Groovy custom sort a map by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686659)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a separate method with `@NonCPS` annotation for that:

```
@NonCPS
def getSorted(def toBeSorted){
    toBeSorted.sort(){ a, b -> b.value <=> a.value }
}
```

And then call it from the pipeline script.

```
Map unsortedMap =[ james  :"silly boy",
         janny  :"Crazy girl",
         jimmy  :"funny man",
         georges:"massive fella" ]
def sortedMap = getSorted(unsortedMap)
```

Answer (score -1):

#### params name

- 1.xx
- 2.xx
- ...

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            inheritFrom 'seunggabi-batch' 
            defaultContainer 'seunggabi-batch'
        }
    }

    environment {
        COUNTRY = "kr"
        ENV = "prod"
        CLASS = "seunggabi.batch.job.SparkSubmitJob"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Run Job') {
            steps {
                script {
                    ARGS = sorted(params).collect { /$it.value/ } join ","
                }
                sh "/app/static/sh/emr.sh 1 20 ${COUNTRY} ${ENV} ${CLASS} \"${ARGS}\""
            }
        }
    }
}

@NonCPS
def sorted(def m){
    m.sort { /$it.key/ }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a simply the duplicate?