# jenkins groovy pipeline sorting

Tags: sorting, jenkins, groovy

it is not possible to correctly sort the sheet.

script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

if (TAGS != 'all') {
    return []
}

def image_id = []

def projectList = new URL("https://gitlab.ru/api/v4/search?scope=projects&search=$PROJECT&private_token=$GITLAB_JENKINS_TOKEN")
def projects = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(projectList.newReader())
projects.each {
 project_id = it.id
}

def repository_name = "$NAME_REPOSITORY"
def id = repository_name.tokenize('/ ')[-1].tokenize('.')[0]
def repository_id = id

def imageList = new URL("https://gitlab.ru/api/v4/projects/$project_id/registry/repositories/$repository_id/tags?per_page=100&private_token=$GITLAB_JENKINS_TOKEN")
def image = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(imageList.newReader())
image.each {
image_id.add(it.name)
}


return image_id
```

result

118/
119/
120/
121/
79/
80/
...

collestions doesn't help.
What are the ways to sort the final sheet

Comment: You can sort a list using the sort method and passing an property you want to sort by: `image_id = image.sort({ it.name })*.name`

Comment: You appear to be attempting to sort an array of numeric strings but want them in numeric order. As strings, they are ordered..

Comment: @ndueck please tell me where to insert this part of the script for correct work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to sort an array of numeric strings but want them in numeric order. As strings, they are ordered.

You want to [groovy sort](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_sorting) the list, but on numerical value (79 before 121), not string ("1,2,1" before "7,9")

I'm not 100% clear on what you reference as "the result", but the solution is applicable where appropriate.

If **projects** is the list,

```
projects.sort(){ a, b -> a.id.toInteger() <=> b.id.toInteger() }.each {
   // process numerically sorted items
}
```

If **image_id** is the list,

```
return image_id.sort(){ a, b -> a.toInteger() <=> b.toInteger() }
```

should return a sorted list.

ie:

```
def list = ['118', '119', '120', '78', '79']

println "raw sort"
list.sort().each {
  println it
}

println "Integer sort"
list.sort(){ a, b -> a.toInteger() <=> b.toInteger() }.each {
  println it
}
return
```

```
raw sort
118
119
120
78
79
Integer sort
78
79
118
119
120
```

If you are trying to [return a **sorted map**, see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13686659/598141).

Comment: @lan W i tried to replace ```return image_id``` on ```return image_id.sort(){ a, b -> a.toInteger() <=> b.toInteger() } ``` and jenkins didn't give any values ​​at all

Comment: Where is this code and where are you **return**ing `image_id` to? per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13686659/598141), you may have to createa `@NonCPS ` method.

Comment: I'm new to great. now the code looks like this

```
def imageList = new URL("https://gitlab.ru/api/v4/projects/$project_id/registry/repositories/$repository_id/tags?per_page=100&private_token=$GITLAB_JENKINS_TOKEN")
def image = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(imageList.newReader())
image.each {
image_id.add(it.name)
}

image_id.sort(){ a, b -> a.toInteger() <=> b.toInteger() }.each {
  println it
}

return image_id
```

I also got used to using NonPCS, but it didn't lead to anything. Lack of experience to correctly apply this module

Comment: I solved the problem, although the method '''return image_id.sort () {a, b -> a.toInteger () <=> b.toInteger ()}''' stops working as soon as a string appears in the list, not a number